# Remove the tag [forum-software]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

[The help center's list of topics](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) specifically excludes the technical platform/software - it says

> If yours is a digital community, please avoid asking questions about a technical feature of your platform.

I take that to mean that discussion of what technical platform to choose in order to get feature X to work is also off topic. However, today a user [posted a question asking just that](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/q/1176/84), saying that the fact that the tag [forum-software](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forum-software) exists made them believe this would be on-topic.

The tag currently has four questions. Two of them aren't actually about specific software; the other two are the one I linked above and another one asking about how to choose software.

Given that the tag hasn't had much use, and that use has been either barely relevant or clearly off-topic, should that tag be removed?

Comment: On the two that were referred to SoftwareRecs, should we replace the tag with another? I agree with the other two questions having the tag removed. Would it make sense to replace `forum-software` with `web-forums` on the recommendation ones?

Comment: I think replacing with `[web-forums]` would work well - that's the kind of software they were asking about, anyway.

Comment: I think this was simple enough. I went ahead and removed the tags from the two questions I mentioned in my answer and changed the two in the recommendation ones. I think I'm going to come up with a stub for the web-forums tag wiki too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the two non-recommendation questions:

This one is asking for advice on how to handle a security breach. I don't think it's specific to forum software at all. I think the tag can be **removed** entirely from this question.

- [My forum security was compromised because I did not patch quickly. I've patched, do I tell my members?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/32/my-forum-security-was-compromised-because-i-did-not-patch-quickly-ive-patched)

This is a multi-part question focused mostly on how to manage tags. It's asking this in the context of forum software. It is also tagged with both [web-forums](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-forums) and [forum-software](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forum-software). I think [forum-software](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forum-software) can be **removed** on this question.

- [Managing and maintaining tagging infrastructure on a community board](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/891/managing-and-maintaining-tagging-infrastructure-on-a-community-board)